# array printing echo multiple times

Tags: shell

I have a list of 3 files

**Files and It's Data inside it:**

**File1.txt**

```
ABC A1
BCD G1
BNC J1
```

**File2.txt**

```
PQR P1
GFH H1
JKD I1
```

**File3.txt**

```
ABJ L1
BkL O1
BGD N1
```

**Below is the keyword list need to be searched**

```
File 1 -> keyword need to be searched is G1 , display keyword exist or not 
File 2 -> keyword need to be searched is H1 , display keyword exist or not 
File 3 -> keyword need to be searched is N0 , display keyword exist or not
```

**My code :**

```
cd /e/FILES/

path='/e/FILES'

arry=(File1.txt  File2.txt File3.txt) 
keyword_array=(G1 H1 N0)

for i in ${arry[@]}
do 
     for j in ${keyword_array[@]}
     do 
           grep $j $path/$i > /dev/null
           status=$?
           
           if [ $status -eq 0 ] 
           then
               echo "Keyword : $j is found in File : $i"
           else
               echo "Keyword : $j is Not found in File : $i"
           fi 
     done
done
```

**Issue :**

How to avoid looping through all elements of an array , just need to loop index to index

```
arr[0]= value && keyword_arr[0] , check keyword_arr[0] value present in arra[0]
```

**My Output is printed with repetition**

```
Keyword : G1 is found in File : File1.txt
Keyword : H1 is Not found in File : File1.txt
Keyword : N0 is Not found in File : File1.txt
Keyword : G1 is Not found in File : File2.txt
Keyword : H1 is found in File : File2.txt
Keyword : N0 is Not found in File : File2.txt
Keyword : G1 is Not found in File : File3.txt
Keyword : H1 is Not found in File : File3.txt
Keyword : N0 is Not found in File : File3.txt
```

**Desired Output :**

```
Keyword : G1 is found in File : File1.txt
Keyword : H1 is found in File : File2.txt
Keyword : N0 is Not found in File : File3.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating the arrays inside a nested loop , hence due to which you see multiple echoes

Nested loops are iterating over each `keyword_array` and trying to grep each of the values inside it

Use the below to achieve the desired output

```
#### test2.sh

cd /e/FILES/

path="/e/FILES/"

arry=(File1.txt  File2.txt File3.txt) 
keyword_array=(G1 H1 N0)


START=0
END=${#arry[@]}
ONE=1
END=$(($END-$ONE))

for i in `seq $START $END`
do 
           cmd="grep ${keyword_array[$i]} $path/${arry[$i]}"
           cmd_out=$($cmd)
           status=$?
           
           if [[ $status -eq 0 ]] 
           then
               echo "Keyword : ${keyword_array[$i]} is found in File : ${arry[$i]}"
           else
               echo "Keyword : ${keyword_array[$i]} is Not found in File : ${arry[$i]}"
           fi
done
```

```
O/P ---> bash test2.sh
Keyword : G1 is found in File : File1.txt
Keyword : H1 is found in File : File2.txt
Keyword : N0 is Not found in File : File3.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your code , I too written a code you can go through it

Answer (score 0):

**Finally i am able to write code without multiple echo getting printed**

**Code : Using nested for loop**

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /e/FILES/ || exit

# Path defined where files are kept 
path='/e/FILES'

# Two arrays
arry=(File1.txt  File2.txt File3.txt) 
keyword_array=(G1 H1 N0)

# Declared a Constant value 
initial_val=0

# Stored count of an array file 
count_array=${#arry[@]}

# Stored count of keyword array 
count_keyword=${#keyword_array[@]}

# Nested for loop
for (( i=initial_val ; i<$((count_array)) ; i++ ))
{
      for (( j=i ; j<$((count_keyword)) ; j++ ))
      {
          if [  "$i" -eq "$j" ]
          then 
                  grep  "${keyword_array[$j]}" $path/"${arry[$i]}" > /dev/null
                  status=$?
                  
                  # Checking the status 
                  if [ $status -eq 0 ]
                  then 
                       echo "Keyword : ${keyword_array[$j]} is found in File : ${arry[$i]}"
                  else
                       echo "Keyword : ${keyword_array[$j]} is Not found in File : ${arry[$i]}" 
                  fi 
          fi        
              
      }     
}
```

**Output :**

```
Keyword : G1 is found in File : File1.txt
Keyword : H1 is found in File : File2.txt
Keyword : N0 is Not found in File : File3.txt
```